# Using Temp table in A VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a clarification on whether we can use Temp tables in VIEWS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a temp table in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711040/using-a-temp-table-in-a-view) which also has a good example of how to do it differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

A view takes a single SELECT statement (which includes UNION of course).

Comment: Then Can I use CTE in my View as my need is to use the same structure as of a stored procedure where I can have Temp tables

Comment: Yes, you can. A CTE is part of a select